# Php Image upload script

Tags: php, upload

Hi thx to tutorials and own hinking I wrote this code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'uploads/';
$description = $_POST['imgdesc'];

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
   mysql_query($query);

echo 'Your file upload was successful!';


} else {
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
}
```

I'm getting this error;

> Notice: Undefined index: userfile in C:\WebServer\htdocs\PicSide\admin\addimage.php on line 16

How to fix it anyone know? And is this correct to upload o server?

Comment: can you post your html form, we need to see that as well? also notices are not exactly errors, errors stops the rest of the script from running whereas notices - depending on the server environment - do not.

Comment: Probably the file input element name is not  userfiles

Comment: 1st Thank you for reply, I noticed I didn't name my input by "userfile" dummy me, but otherwise is this code correct?

Comment: @creminsn, Notices are not errors? I wonder why it is an option in PHP **error** reporting? =oP It is an error, just a less severe error. Notices should be fixed as having them means the code is not properly being done to account for variables not existing, which does not make robust code.

Comment: You shouldn't be telling anyone to CHMOD directories to 777.  CHMODing to 777 is a very amateurish way to get around actually dealing with user file permissions in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @cryptic, poor choice of words on my part. but what I said about notices not halting execution whereas errors will, is true.

Comment: Guys, everything works fine except adding rows to MYSQL :(  I cannot find the problem

Comment: Probably because you didn't do mysql_connect and mysql_select_db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, what your error means is that you don't have the following (or somewhat similar) element in your form:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
```

The important part in this is the actual `name="userfile"` which specifies the key in the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found it out 1min after posting this, I noticed to late, sorry for unnecessary post

Comment: @Piggie, I personally would mark ninetwozero's as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to concat:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)";
```

Should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES (".$filename.", ".$description.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
</form>

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'uploads/';
$description = $_POST['imgdesc'];
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
   mysql_query($query);

echo 'Your file upload was successful!';


}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Comment: Funny.  Great solution