# uploading files in yii

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I'am trying to upload media files (video, audio, images), the upload process done successfully, but in case of video uploading I don't find the video in it's directory on the server, this the code:

```
$model->fileName=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'fileName');
if($model->save()){
                         $model->fileName->saveAs(getcwd()."/files/video/".$u->userName."/".$model->fileName);
```

so, when I open this directing I don't find the uploaded video, what is the problem here?
and can you give me php functions to get the file type and size?
thank you :)

Comment: [Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520818/uploading-video-to-server-using-php) to upload a video in the server

Comment: "/files/video/" have you given the write permission to this folder?

Comment: yes, there is no problems with permissions.

Comment: How big is the video file? Is it bigger than the allowed POST value?

Comment: I want to make the maximum video size allowed is 1 GB